# How to limit the result of the quota command in bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, awk, text-processing

I have a simple question but i didn't find a method to implement it, in case I need to get only the free space value of the quota command.

Scenery: `$ quota -s abdalazizdemoura` Result:

```
Disk quotas for user abdalazizdemoura (uid 3944):
     Filesystem   space   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
/dev/mapper/work-home
                  5068M      0K   5120M            246k       0       0
/dev/mapper/work-lxc
                   828K      0K  20480K              26       0       0
```

I specifically need the output of /dev/mapper/work-home partition to **space** or **limit** and nothing else.

Comment: It is a Logical Volume Group of /home, that has several directories customers in it. 
Exemple /home/abdalazizdemoura/ or /home/marcos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
quota -w -s abdalazizdemoura | awk '/\/dev\/mapper\/work-home/ {print $2}'
5068M
quota -w -s abdalazizdemoura | awk '/\/dev\/mapper\/work-home/ {print $4}'
5120M
```